# Trying to understand method signature changes spanning assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dependencies, .net-assembly

We ran into a strange problem with a promotion and I'm hoping I'll be able to explain it with code.  I want to understand why it behaves in the manner it is.

Assembly 1

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static string DoStuff()
    {
        // Do something

        return "some string";
    }
}
```

Assembly 2:

```
public class Bar
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // I realize the below is not what should be done for catching exceptions, as the exception is never thrown due to the return, and seems unnecessary either way... 
        // this is inherited code and has not been modified to correct.

        try
        {
            var someValue = Foo.DoStuff();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Requirements changed so that DoStuff would need to take in a parameter, the value of which would change the behavior slightly.  Note that only assembly 1.Foo is changing.

New Foo

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static string DoStuff(bool someBool = false)
    {
        // Do something

        return "some string";
    }
}
```

This recompiled fine, and Assembly 2 was able to successfully utilize the changed method signature without complaint.  My check in was performed, and project dlls that had changes were promoted (note this was only Assembly 1 dll).

After promotion we found out that Assembly 2 was failing on the Foo.DoStuff() call - unfortunately I cannot provide an exception as the above code was swallowing it.

Even though no actual code changed in Assembly 2, it did seem to have an impact on the dll on recompile, even though the method signature - at least in my mind - is the same due to providing a default value for the new parameter.

I used dotnet peek in order to peek at the "old dll" and the "new dlls" (even though no code change to that assembly and did note a difference in the two DLLs in that in the old DLL, the default value parameter was not supplied, but in the recompiled, the default value parameter was supplied.

I guess my question(s) boil down to this:

1. Why does the compiled code on assembly 2 change based on a method signature that (at least I think) should be transparent?
2. Would the method of avoiding a situation like this just be "deploy everything"? Rather than trying to deploy based on code changes?  Note that DLLs are not checked in, so there was no actual "code change" to assembly 2, though the DLL was different based on the changes to Assembly 1.

Comment: Another method of avoiding this situation would be to leave the parameter-less method in place and have it call the new method with a default value, rather than specifying a default in the method signature: `public static string DoStuff() { return DoStuff(false); }`. Also would be helpful to remove the `return` from that catch (or at least log the exception first).

Comment: @RufusL If I could do it all again, knowing what I know now, that would have definitely been the approach I would have taken ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the compiled code on assembly 2 change based on a method signature that (at least I think) should be transparent?

No, it shouldn't. When you don't specify an argument to correspond with an optional parameter, the default value is provided at the call site - i.e. assembly 2 in your case. That's how optional parameters work in C#. It's a pain, but that's life.

> Would the method of avoiding a situation like this just be "deploy everything"?

Yes. Basically, the *meaning* of the source in assembly 2 has changed even though the code itself hasn't - so the compiled code has changed, and it needs to be redeployed.

You can see subtle breaking changes like this in other cases, too - where the same old "client" code compiles against new "receiving" code, but has a different meaning. Two examples:

- Suppose you change a method signature from `Foo(long x)` to `Foo(int x)` but at the call site, you only call it as `Foo(5)`... that compiles in both cases, but to different code.
- Suppose you have change a method signature from `Foo(int x, int y)` to `Foo(int y, int x)` and you have a call of `Foo(x: 5, y: 2)`... again, the *meaning* of the code changes from `Foo(5, 2)` to `Foo(2, 5)`, if you see what I mean. Recompiling the unchanged source code against the new "receiving" code will change the behaviour.
- Suppose you have a constant in assembly 1, e.g. `public const string Foo = "Foo";`. If you change that to `public const string Foo = "Bar"`, but don't recompile assemblies *using* the constant, those assemblies will still use a value of "Foo". (This goes for default values of optional parameters, too.)

Comment: Would a better solution be to leave the parameter-less version of `DoStuff()` in place and have it call the parameterized overload with the default value? Something like: `public static string DoStuff() { return DoStuff(false); }`? Or does this have it's own set of problems?

Comment: @RufusL: That's a more backwardly-compatible way of doing it, yes - it really depends on whether redeploying everything is actually an issue.,

Comment: thanks, I hadn't thought of your "suppose" scenarios before, that helps!